# Python - Basic Explanation for Someone Trying to Understand (CSV, Excel)

Tags: python, excel, csv, syntax-error

I have go through this code line by line and explain each step. However, as I am extremely new to python (like this is my first work with it) I am very confused as to what this function is doing/why I am getting an error message. Any help would be appreciated!

```
print("Exercise 2 begins")
import csv  
c = 0       
t = 0      

with open('adele.csv','r') as csvfile:
    csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')  
for line in csvdata:  
    t = t + 1         
    try:
        if 'grammy' in line[5]:  
            c = c + 1            
            print(c + ": " + t + ": " + str(line[5]))   # (7) Describe the purpose of this line
    except IndexError:           
        pass                    

csvfile.close()
print("Exercise 2 ends\n")
```

Comment: Based on the answers to [this Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) and the linked duplicates, I'm voting to close as too broad.  There are multiple, entirely independent questions here (and the code itself contains both indentation errors -- possibly introduced due to posting -- and lines which don't make much sense.)

Comment: Surely you can already answer (1), so what was the error message? StackOverflow is not a homework service so please show some effort to solve your own problems first. Please also read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DSM probably the indentation errors are the answer to (1) :)

Comment: I've gotten two different error messages based on where I've saved the file - I was asking what the error message was for OTHERs because I'm not sure what is wrong. One is "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 83: invalid continuation byte" and the other was a "FileNotFound". Sorry if this was not clear enough - I am just confused as to why there are two different errors?

Comment: As for the indentation, as I said I'm SUPER new to this and wasn't aware that indentation can actually cause errors? Is that true? I was given this to run in a free Intro to Python class but I want to make sure I understand each line of code - I don't just want to solve the error. Sorry if this is too much information to ask, I just am trying to get a full understanding

Answer (score 1):

The error message is that the code should be indented after `for line in csvdata:`.

```
print("Exercise 2 begins")

import csv  # Include csv package to allow processing of csv files
c = 0       # Initialize a variable "c" with value "0"
t = 0       # Initialize a variable "t" with value "0"

# (1)  You will run into an error when running this code. 
#      What is the error message? 
#      What does the message mean and how do you fix it?

with open('adele.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t') # (2) What does this line mean
    for line in csvdata:                          # (3) What does this line mean
        t = t + 1         # (4) Describe the purpose of this line
        try:
            if 'grammy' in line[5]:  # (5) What does this line mean and 
                                     # what is in line[5]
                c = c + 1            # (6) What does this line mean
                print(c + ": " + t + ": " + str(line[5])) # (7) What does this line mean
        except IndexError:           
            pass
```

Depending on `adele.csv`, this code may or may not work. Try it, and try to understand what it does and how. Without error message, it will be easier to understand.

This code might check the number of grammy awards won by Adele, but it's hard to say without seeing `adele.csv`.